# file_get_contents works right on localhost not on shared hosting

Tags: php, instagram, file-get-contents, shared-hosting

Here's a simple example this code gets any Instagram user's followers count without API.

```
$otherPage = 'nasa';
$response = file_get_contents("https://www.instagram.com/$otherPage/?__a=1");
if ($response !== false) {
    $data = json_decode($response, true);
    if ($data !== null) {
        $follows = $data['graphql']['user']['edge_follow']['count'];
        $followedBy = $data['graphql']['user']['edge_followed_by']['count'];
        echo $follows . ' and ' . $followedBy;
    }
}
```

This code working in my localhost and also on my friend's server but in my shared hosting it's not working :(

The `file_get_contents` function working well but only with the internal files not online links.

Anyone understand why?

Answer (score 3):

This is likely due to the fact that hosting provider has disabled [`allow_url_fopen`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php) in configuration.

The default option is to be enabled, which is probably true on both your / your friend's server, it is common for shared hosting providers to disable this and other things that could be malicious / have the potential to impact other sites running on the same host.

To confirm, try fetching the value, if this is disabled, you will not be able to call *fopen* from remote URIs.

```
echo ini_get("allow_url_fopen");
```

Comment: Thank you very much I will try to contact them to enable this for me

Comment: It's enabled in my php.init file allow_url_fopen = On

Comment: Also, i have checked by something like this : if ( ini_get( 'allow_url_fopen' ) == 1) and it's return true

Comment: Sometimes you can Enable / Disable the allow_url_fopen on the PHP configuration panel of your Hosting provider